# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( async await [IONIC 3]

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this project on IONIC that work well on browser but in android device fail with this error. For some reason the function async/await doesn't work .

I think that with es2018 sould be working . Can some one have a look on my config ?

run the app with

```
ionic cordova run android
```

and a few seconds later this is the output console from AndroidStudio logcat

```
 "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

08-05 16:03:36.417 32442-32442/chess.pidoweb I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1343)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", source: http://192.168.0.85:8100/build/main.js (1343)
```

**The error is this async/await function**

```
 async webGoogleLogin() {
        try {
           ... some code ..
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

**CONFIGURATION:**

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="chess.pidoweb" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Pido IONIC</name>
    <description>""</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8100/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="tel:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="mailto:*" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="default" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <universal-links>
        <host name="https://n3q8p.app.goo.gl/jdXk" scheme="https" />
        <host name="AUTH_DOMAIN" scheme="https">
            <path url="/__/auth/callback" />
        </host>
    </universal-links>
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="info.protonet.imageresizer" spec="~0.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^1.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="^5.3.0">
        <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="com.googleusercontent.apps.781145103219-a87b3bd7d7858i8lrr2531nm8ml2bj6c" />
        <variable name="WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID" value="781145103219-vn75hrm8tv0b54hkck4dokv5nnr0pvao.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="^2.4.0">
        <variable name="XWALK_VERSION" value="22+" />
        <variable name="XWALK_LITEVERSION" value="xwalk_core_library_canary:17+" />
        <variable name="XWALK_COMMANDLINE" value="--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect" />
        <variable name="XWALK_MODE" value="embedded" />
        <variable name="XWALK_MULTIPLEAPK" value="true" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3">
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativestorage" spec="^2.3.2" />
        <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <engine name="browser" spec="5.0.3" />
    <engine name="android" spec="7.0.0" />
</widget>
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 8,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2018"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2018",
    "types" : ["node"],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/__tests__/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "pidoionic",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "config": {
    "ionic_webpack": "config/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.10.1",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-analytics": "^4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-resizer": "^4.6.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite-porter": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.11.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.3",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.5-next",
    "asyncawait": "^1.0.7",
    "cordova": "^8.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "7.0.0",
    "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": "^1.4.4",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview": "^2.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "^1.8.3",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^5.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "^2.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": "^1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^2.3.3",
    "firebase": "^4.13.1",
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "imagemin": "^5.3.1",
    "info.protonet.imageresizer": "^0.1.1",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "4.2.6",
    "local-storage": "^1.4.2",
    "mercadopago": "^1.0.13",
    "moment": "^1.7.2",
    "ng2-reactive-forms-validators": "^1.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.7",
    "yarn": "^1.9.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/google.analytics": "0.0.39",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.11",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.4",
    "ionic": "3.9.2",
    "sql.js": "^0.5.0",
    "ts-node": "7.0.0",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.11",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "info.protonet.imageresizer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googleplus": {
        "REVERSED_CLIENT_ID": "com.googleusercontent.apps.781145103219-a87b3bd7d7858i8lrr2531nm8ml2bj6c",
        "WEB_APPLICATION_CLIENT_ID": "781145103219-vn75hrm8tv0b54hkck4dokv5nnr0pvao.apps.googleusercontent.com"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview": {
        "XWALK_VERSION": "22+",
        "XWALK_LITEVERSION": "xwalk_core_library_canary:17+",
        "XWALK_COMMANDLINE": "--disable-pull-to-refresh-effect",
        "XWALK_MODE": "embedded",
        "XWALK_MULTIPLEAPK": "true"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-android-support-gradle-release": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

IONIC INFO

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 3.9.2
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
   Cordova Platforms     : not available

System:

   NodeJS : v8.11.1 (D:\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 5.6.0
   OS     : Windows 10

Environment:

   ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: Yes, In my case was the target on to my tsconfig.json, the solution was modify the target from "es2018" to "es2015"